# Should System Protection be enabled on all O.S. partitions together?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-8, restore

I have 2 HDDs, both GPT, HDD1 has w10-64 in one partition, HDD2 has w8.1.1-64 in one partition, all other partitions are data (meaning, without any o.s. on those partitions).

When I am in w10, I have enabled system protection only for that w10 (not for w8.1), similarly, When I am in w8.1, I have enabled system protection only for that w8.1 (not for w10).

is it ok? Because when I am in one o.s. then I am not changing anything in the other o.s. so other os' previously made restore points should remain intact.

However, when I go to System Restore in either o.s., it shows restore points I had made or some software has created. I wonder what is the meaning of it showing w8.1 restore points when I am logged in to w10, and it showing w10 restore points when I am logged in to w8.1? Does it mean it creates restore points for all o.s. together? and does it restore all o.s. together to some restore point?

So, is it ok to enable System Protection only for the o.s. partition I am currently in? 
or Should System Protection be enabled on all O.S. partitions together?

Thanks.

Comment: no no, it is not about whether restore is useful or not. It is useful. I have used it myself several time to rescue me from deep mess.

Comment: The question is : Whether I have to simultaneously enable protection for both o.s. when I am in either o.s.?